# WP8 async method in scheduled task

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, asynchronous, scheduled-tasks

I am trying to make live tile which uses data from DownloadStringAsync method.

```
protected override void  OnInvoke(ScheduledTask task){
  WebClient web = new WebClient();
  web.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("website"));
  web.DownloadStringCompleted += web_DownloadStringCompleted;
  StandardTileData data = new StandardTileData();
  ShellTile tile = ShellTile.ActiveTiles.First();
  data.BackContent = string;
  tile.Update(data);
}

void web_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, 
                                 DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
   string=e.result ; 
} // example
```

string is returning null all the time. I think it is because of async operation. Somehow if I can make it sync maybe it can work. any ideas ? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a [Race Condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) Since the download operation is asynchronous, the 'string' variable (which should not compile BTW) will not necessary be updated when you will read it's value to set the BackContent.

Try this with the [Async/Await](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx) keywords:

```
protected async override void  OnInvoke(ScheduledTask task)
{
   var web = new Webclient();
   var result = await web.DownloadStringTaskAsync(new Uri("website"));
   StandardTileData data = new StandardTileData();
   ShellTile tile = ShellTile.ActiveTiles.First();
   data.BackContent = result;
   tile.Update(data);
 }
```

If you can't use [DownloadStringTaskAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh138332%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in your WP8 App, then try using [TaskCompletionSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd449174%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to accomplish the same thing, as exampled in this [post](http://blog.galasoft.ch/posts/2013/01/using-asyncawait-with-webclient-in-windows-phone-8-or-taskcompletionsource-saves-the-day/) .

```
protected async override void  OnInvoke(ScheduledTask task)
{
   var result = await DownloadStringTaskAsync (new Uri("website"));     
   StandardTileData data = new StandardTileData();
   ShellTile tile = ShellTile.ActiveTiles.First();
   data.BackContent = result;
   tile.Update(data);
 }

   public Task<string> DownloadStringTaskAsync(Uri address)
   {
      var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
      var client = new WebClient();
      client.DownloadStringCompleted += (s, e) =>
      {
         if (e.Error == null)
         {
             tcs.SetResult(e.Result);
         }
         else
         {
             tcs.SetException(e.Error);
         }
     };

     client.DownloadStringAsync(address);

     return tcs.Task;
 }
```

Here are an [example 1](http://blog.galasoft.ch/posts/2013/01/using-asyncawait-with-webclient-in-windows-phone-8-or-taskcompletionsource-saves-the-day/) & [example 2](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Asynchronous_Programming_For_Windows_Phone_8) & [example 3 from MSDN](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kevinash/archive/2012/02/21/async-ctp-task-based-asynchronous-programming-for-windows-phone.aspx) for using the Async/Await keyword with WebClient in Windows Phone 8.

Since you are using WP8, then you might need to add the Nuget package for the Async/Await keyword. just run

> install-package Microsoft.Bcl.Async

In the [Package Manager](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/Using-the-Package-Manager-Console) Console. Or use Nuget GUI to download it (search for 'async')

Comment: hi, thanks for answer. for the second line I replaced as " var result = await web.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("website"));" its saying error cannot await "void" . I will check the example links now

Comment: @user3343556 Please call DownloadStringTaskAsync and not DownloadStringAsync :)